# Easiest way to split a string based on number of whitespaces in Python3

Tags: regex, string, python-3.x

I have a sentence such as.

> ```
> Ok I want to split            this sentence completely, Using that big space gap.
> ```

```
    with open("Sample2.txt","r") as f:
      for line in f:
        B.append(line.split("    "))
        print (B)
```

I get an ***OUTPUT*** like so:

```
[['Ok I want to split', '', '', 'this sentence completely, Using that big space gap.\n']]
```

Logically this is right. But I don't want the 2 extra entries in between the split.

***IDEAL OUTPUT*** should be:

```
[['Ok I want to split','this sentence completely, Using In that big space gap.\n']]
```

**EDIT:** Assume That there are an arbitrary number of spaces between the splits, and it isn't possible to manually keep counting them.

Oh, and what can I do about that annoying '\n' ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use a regex:

```
>>> re.split(r' {4,}', s)
['Ok I want to split', 'this sentence completely. Using that big space gap.']
```

That version will split on "4 or more spaces".

If you want to drop the `\n`, use `foo.rstrip()` where `foo` is your string.

Answer (score 1):

Use regexp `+` (space followed by a 1+ spaces), and strip the input string to get rid of `\n`.

```
import re
re.split(r'  +', a.strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

Do splitting on one more than one spaces or space exists next to a dot.

```
re.split(r'\s{2,}|(?<=\.)\s+', strin)
```

*Example:*

```
>>> h = 'Ok I want to split            this sentence completely. Using that big space gap.'
>>> re.split(r'\s{2,}|(?<=\.)\s+', h)
['Ok I want to split', 'this sentence completely.', 'Using that big space gap.']
>>>
```